# When to use which Data Structure?

Tags: java, data-structures

I am studying Data Structures in a Fundamentals of Software Development course. I have encountered the following data structures:

- Structs
- Arrays
- Lists
- Queues
- Hash Tables

... among others. I have a good understanding of how they work, but I'm struggling to understand when and where to use them.

I can identify the use of the Queue Data structure, as this would be helpful in printer and/or thread queuing and prioritizing.

Knowing the strengths and weaknesses of a data structure and implementing it in code are different things, and I am finding the former difficult.

What is a simple example of the use of each of the data structures listed above?

For example:

**Queue:** first-in, first-out → used for printer queue to queue docs

Comment: Do you even know what each data structure does? Once you know, it should be obvious when to use them.

Comment: Knowing what they do and when and how to implement them in code are 2 completely different things. I even know my language support but cannot see any reason to use them instead of an array. In my experience an Array has always covered what I needed. Never needed to use a hash table to make searching, inserting and deleting faster. Never needed a tree or a heap. The only other data structure that I can see a use for may be a queue for printer or thread queueing. I cannot really identify where I would use the others. I am asking for a simple example of each. If that makes any sense.

Comment: I found the answer to my question in a tutorial on the lynda website. As a summary it comes down to the data and not the data structure. How much data you have, how often does it change, do you need to sort it. And based on your requirements you select your structure. As little sense as it made before, I do understand it now. Thanks for all the feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had trouble understanding them when i first started programming and so i decided to give a heads up to start with.

I am trying to be as simple as possible. Try Oracle Docs fro further details

---

**Struct:** When ever you need Object like structure, where you can group related data, use structs. Structs are very rarely used in java though(as objects are created in their place)

**Arrays:** Arrays are contiguous memory. when ever you want fixed time access based on index, unlike linkedlist, arrays are very fast and so use them.

But the backlog with arrays is that you need to know the size at the time of initialization. Also arrays does not support higher level methods such as add(), remove(), clear(),contains(), indexOf() etc.

---

**List:** is an interface which can be implemented using Arrays(ArrayList)
 or LinkedLists (LinkedList). They support all the higher level methods specified earlier.

Also Lists re-sizes themselves whenever it is getting out of space. You can specify the initial size which the underlying Arrays or LinkedLists will be created, but whenever the limit is reached, it created the underlying structure with a bigger size and then copies the contents of the initial one.

---

**Queue or Stack:** is an implementation technique and not really a data structure. If you want FIFO implementation, you implement Queue on either Arrays or LinkedList(yes, you can implement this technique on both these data structures)
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Structures/Stacks_and_Queues

---

**HashMap:** Hashmap is used whenever you want to store key value pairs. if you notice, you cannot use arrays or linked lists or any other mentioned data structure for this purpose. a key can be any thing from String to Object(but note that it has to be an object and cannot be a primitive) and a value can also be any object

---

google out each data structure for more details

Comment: Prasad, thank you so much. This was exactly what I was looking for. I have read all the correct terms and know that an Array is contiguous in the memory and a list is not and that the stack is FILO compared to a queue that is FIFO. Although I studied this information I could not identify (in simple terms) when to use which. I appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need. If you read and learn more about these data structures you will find convenient ways for their implementation.

Maybe read this book? [http://www.amazon.com/Data-Structures-Abstraction-Design-Using/dp/0470128704](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470128704)

Comment: Thank you for the book recommendation I will definitely check it out

Answer (score 0):

All these data structures are used based on their needs in the program. Try to find advantages of one data structure to the other. That should get things more clear for you.What I say wouldn't be much clear, but i'll give it a shot

Like for example,

Structs are used to create a data type, say you want to have a data type for `Book` & have the names of the book[Book Structure](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm).

Lists are easier to access both ways if you use linked lists & are better than array some times. Queues, well, you can imagine them as real life queues, First In will be First Out. So you can use them when you need to set this priority.

Like I said, looking for advantages of one over the other should get things clear for you.